# The expression of points near a critical point

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional differensiable submanifold of euclidean $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $P_0$ be a point of $\mathbb{R}^N-X$ and denote by
$\phi(P)=|P-P_0|$, the distance function from $P_0$ to $P$. The critical points of $\phi$, the points where the vector $P-P_0$ is orthogonal to $X$.

Let $P$ be a critical point for the distance function $\phi$. Choose rectangular coordinates $x_l, ..., x_n, ..., x_N$, in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with origin at $P$ and with the sp $x_{n+1} = ... = x_N = 0$ as tangent space to $X$ at $P$. Then $x_1,..., X_n$ can used as local coordinates in $X$ at $P$. Let the fixed point $P_0$ have coordinates $(0,..., 0, a_1,.., a_{N-n}$).

My question is, why near $P$, $X$ is represented by equations of the form
$x_{n+i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^nb_{ij}^ix_ix_j+H^i(x_1,...,x_n)$ for $1\le i\le N-n$? where $H^i$  together with its first and second partial derivatives vanish at  $P$.

Comment: What you wrote is simply false, you cannot assume that 2nd partial derivatives of $H^i$'s vanish. Other than that, this has nothing to do with critical points of the distance function: Every submanifold locally is the graph of a smooth function (this is the implicit function theorem). After that, just use Taylor's formula.

Comment: @MoisheCohen the $H^i$ contains the $\sum\partial g_j(p)/\partial x_i(x_i-p_i)+$ higher derivatives, where $x_{n+j}=g_j(x_1,...,x_n)$. But $\sum\partial g_j(p)/\partial x_i(x_i-p_i)$ might not be $0$, and the higher derivatives terms after first and second derivatives would go to $0$ since they are in the form of $(x_i-p_i)(x_j-p_j)(x_t-p_t)R(x_1,...,x_n)$.  So I think the thing is we cannot assume the first derivatives of $H^i$ vanish.